# do a select on two tables and the result allows access to fields of these two selected tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im doing a search system and Im having some problems.

I need to search in two tables (news and pages), I already had sucess doing my search system for just one table, but for two tables its not easy to do.

I already use a select statment with two tables using UNION because I want to show number of search results, that is number of returned rows of my first sql statment.

But now I need to do a select statment that allows me to acess all fields of my news table and all fields of my pages table.

I need to acess in my news table this fields: id, title, content, link, date, nViews

I need to acess in my pages table this fields: id, title, content, link

Im trying to do this also with UNION, but in this case Im not having any row returning.

Do you see what I have wrong in my code?

```
<?php
//first I get my $search keyword
$search = $url[1];

$pdo = connecting();
//then I want to show number of returned rows for keyword searched
$readALL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT title,content FROM news WHERE title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? 
                          UNION SELECT title,content FROM pages WHERE title LIKE ? OR content like ?");
$readALL->bindValue(1,"%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$readALL->bindValue(2,"%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$readALL->bindValue(3,"%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$readALL->bindValue(4,"%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$readALL->execute();
//I show number of returned rows
echo '<p>Your search keyword returned <strong>'.$readALL->rowCount().'</strong> results!</p>';
//If dont return any rows I show a error message
if($readALL->rowCount() <=0){
    echo 'Sorry but we didnt found any result for your keyword search.';
}
else{
    //If return rows I want to show, if it is a page result I want to show title and link that I have in my page table
    //if it is a news result I want to show title and link that I have in my news table and also date of news
    echo '<ul class="searchlist">';
            $readALL2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE status = ? AND title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? LIMIT 0,4
                                      UNION SELECT * FROM pages where title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ? LIMIT 0,4"); 
            $readALL2->bindValue(1, '1');
            $readALL2->bindValue(2, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $readALL2->bindValue(3, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $readALL2->bindValue(4, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $readALL2->execute();   

            while ($result = $readALL2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo '<li>';
                    echo '<img src="'.BASE.'/uploads/news/'.$result['thumb'].'"/>';
                    echo '<a href="'.BASE.'/news/'.$result['id_news'].'">'.$result['title'].'</a>';
                    //if it is a news result I also want to show data on my list
                    //echo '<span id="date">'.$result['data'].'</span>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
    echo ' </ul>';
    //but how can I do my select statement to have access to my news table fields and my page table fields??
}
?>
```

This is my news table:

[image]

This is my pages table:

[image]

**When I search on my form for keyword "doc" I get this:**

Your are searching for keyword: "doc"

your search returned 2 results!

Array ( [id_news] => 472 [thumb] => 2014/07/title-of-news-11405372264.png [title] => Documents [content] => Link 1, Link 2 [ofte] => 2014-07-14 23:11:04 [views] => 0 [author] => 1 [category] => 116 [status] => 1  [id] => 1 [link] => documents ) image of news Documents

Array ( [id_news] => 473 [thumb] => 2014/07/title-of-news-21405372282.png [title] => Documents [content] => Link 1, Link 2 [ofte] => 2014-07-14 23:11:22 [views] => 0 [author] => 1 [category] => 115 [status] => 1  [id] => 1 [link] => documents ) image of news Documents

Array ( [id_news] => 472 [thumb] => 2014/07/title-of-news-11405372264.png [title] => About [content] => we are a company... [ofte] => 2014-07-14 23:11:04 [views] => 0 [author] => 1 [category] => 116 [status] => 1  [id] => 2 [link] => about ) image of news About

Array ( [id_news] => 473 [thumb] => 2014/07/title-of-news-21405372282.png [title] => About [content] => we are a company... [ofte] => 2014-07-14 23:11:22 [views] => 0 [author] => 1 [category] => 115 [status] => 1  [id] => 2 [link] => about ) image of news About

Array ( [id_news] => 472 [thumb] => 2014/07/title-of-news-11405372264.png [title] => Contacts [content] => Email: test@email.com [ofte] => 2014-07-14 23:11:04 [views] => 0 [author] => 1 [category] => 116 [status] => 1  [id] => 3 [link] => contacts ) image of news Contacts

Array ( [id_news] => 473 [thumb] => 2014/07/title-of-news-21405372282.png [title] => Contacts [content] => Email: test@email.com [ofte] => 2014-07-14 23:11:22 [views] => 0 [author] => 1 [category] => 115 [status] => 1  [id] => 3 [link] => contacts ) image of news Contacts

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gordon Linoff. I forgot to put here my last bindValue. But in my example I have correctly and its not working! I update my question with your correction.

Answer (score 1):

To query 2 tables, and have the result set contain columns from both tables:

```
SELECT n.id, n.status, n.views,  p.id, p.title
FROM news n, pages p
WHERE n.status = ? 
AND p.title = ?
...
```

To simplify my answer I have omitted most of your required columns, but you simply add more to the select statement. Of course, you can always use

```
SELECT n.*, p.*
```

To select all columns from both tables.

Update:

For your specific scenario, try:

```
SELECT n.*, p.* 
FROM news n, pages p
WHERE n.title LIKE ?
  OR n.content LIKE ?
  OR p.title LIKE ?
  OR p.content LIKE ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But its not working correctly. In my first sql statment where I get number of rows returned for searched keyword Im getting 3 rows returned with my keyword "doc". In my second sql like you said, Im getting 7 returned rows, and its wrong because I just have 3 rows with my condition. Im trying like this: SELECT * FROM news, pages
 WHERE news.status = ? AND news.title LIKE ? OR news.content LIKE ?
 AND pages.title LIKE ? OR pages.content LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?,?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex, but I have same result. Im getting 7results and was supposed to be only 3!

Comment: Bare in mind that if the same string is found in the title of news and the title of a page, it will return a row for each. If this changes things..

Comment: I know Alex, but I just have 3 records with title or content like '%doc%', and my select as you said return 7 results! But my first with union it is correct, it returns 3 rows.

Comment: Can you update your question by doing a print_r on the 7 rows that it returns

Comment: @OzzC I strongly suspect why this is happening, and have a likely fix. But to prevent giving only half an answer, please can you also update your answer to replace the code with the new code that you are using, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a new question trying to explain and detail everything. If you have some time take a look! And really Thanks for all the help.